# stream_context_create Authorization not working

Tags: php, xml

If i login using brower it works but from code it gives Authorization error.

```
 $request='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><req:KnownTrackingRequest xmlns:req="http://www.dhl.de"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.deTrackingRequestKnown.xsd">
<Request>
    <ServiceHeader>
        <MessageTime>2002-06-25T11:28:56-08:00</MessageTime>
        <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678</MessageReference>

    </ServiceHeader>
</Request>
<LanguageCode>de</LanguageCode>
<AWBNumber>8564385550</AWBNumber>
<LevelOfDetails>ALL_CHECK_POINTS</LevelOfDetails>
<PiecesEnabled>S</PiecesEnabled></req:KnownTrackingRequest>';

        $context = stream_context_create(
            array(
                'http' => array(
                    'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("a98098880:NEO_dhl83#") . "\r\n" .
                        "Content-type: text/xml \r\n"
                )
            )
        );
      $response = file_get_contents("https://cig.dhl.de/services/sandbox/rest/sendungsverfolgung" . "?xml=" . urlencode($request), false, $context);
```

if login with browser this username password works but not like this, Dont know if I am making some mistake.